# Unique count and sort of a stream of data for a period of time

Tags: linux, bash, awk, uniq

I want to sort/get unique count from a live stream for a certain period of time:

```
some-stream | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

For example, `some-stream` here can be `tcpdump -i any | awk '{print $3}'` to give you list of IPs.

Is it possible to constantly get an update of the unique counts as the stream updates in real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

***Solution 1st:*** To get all the values of 3rd column of server names(if you have IPs in 3rd column we could change regex in solution too)

```
tcpdump -i any |stdbuf -oL  awk '$3 ~ /\.com/{match($3,/.*\.com/);print substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

***Solution 2nd:*** To get the unique servers list following may help you in same:

```
tcpdump -i any |stdbuf -oL  awk '$3 ~ /\.com/{match($3,/.*\.com/);if(!a[substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++){print substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH);a[substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)]}}'
```

***OR***

```
tcpdump -i any |
stdbuf -oL  awk '$3 ~ /\.com/{
                               match($3,/.*\.com/);
                               if(!a[substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++){
                               print substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH);
                               a[substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)]}
}'
```

Comment: This doesn't show the count of each unique report. It's just showing the number of unique items

Comment: @Kousha, please post the output of your command then I could tune my code accordingly, it is very difficult else.